# What effect will branch prediction have on the following C loop?

Tags: c, android-ndk, compiler-optimization, micro-optimization, branch-prediction

My experience with C is relatively modest, and I lack good understanding of its compiled output on modern CPUs. The context: I'm working on image processing for an Android app. I have read that branch-free machine code is preferred for inner loops, so I'd like to know whether there could be a significant performance difference between something like this:

```
if (p)      { double for loop, computing f() }

else if (q) { double for loop, computing g() }

else        { double for loop, computing h() }
```

Versus the less verbose version which does the condition checking within the loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < xRes; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < yRes; j++)
    {
        image[i][j] = p ? f() : (q ? g() : h());
    }
}
```

In this code, p and q are expressions like `mode == 3`, where `mode` is passed into the function and never changed within it. I have three simple questions:

(1) Would the first, more verbose version compile to more efficient code than the second version?

(2) For the second version, would performance improve if I evaluate and store the results of `p` and `q` above the loop, so I can replace the boolean expressions in the loop with variables?

(3) Should I even be worried about this, or will branch prediction (or some other optimization) ensure the boolean expressions in the loop(s) are almost never evaluated anyway?

Finally, I'd be delighted if someone can say whether the answers to these 3 questions depend on the architecture. I'm interested in the main Android NDK platforms: ARM, MIPS, x86 etc. My thanks in advance!

Comment: optimization will remove the evaluation of p and q out of the loop, but not the branch. Move the conditionals out of the loop and have 3 copies of the double loop.

Comment: stark, that was my initial suspicion, but I am disappointed to hear it confirmed. For best performance, it is really necessary to write the same loop 3 times?

Comment: Actually, it won't make much difference due to the branching in the loops and the wait for memory reads and writes.  Cache effects are difficult to get right.

Comment: I see good answers were given in this almost identical question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12251160/performance-of-branch-prediction-in-a-loop.  So I will wait a while to see if someone has an answer more specific to MIPS and ARM, and close this question as a duplicate if they don't.

Comment: Architecture isn't going to change if your compiler can see that `p` and `q` will be the same each loop iteration to be able to pull the conditional out of the loop.

Comment: If you call a function on a per pixel basis, you are fxxxed anyway.  ----by your smart compiler.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the question was already well-answered [here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12251160/performance-of-branch-prediction-in-a-loop) the compiler probably performs *loop unswitching*, removing the conditional from the loop and automatically generating 3 copies of the loop, just like [stark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1216776/stark) suggested. Moreover, from comments given there and above, it seems branch prediction works very well for loops like these.